# How to create OSGI project in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, osgi, directory-structure

I am trying to create an OSGI project on IntelliJ Idea but so far couldn't make it. I can change the facet after creating a Java project but it isn't the one I want.

In eclipse, while I am creating the project ( Plugin Project ) I can select it to be an OSGI project thus IDE helps me to create required project structure.

But in IntelliJ Idea it is not - at least I couldn't find it -

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look to [Osmorc](http://www.osmorc.org/). Its for OSGi development in Intellij. If you are familiar with Maven you can use a combination of Bnd Framework and [maven-bundle-plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html). With the last one you are independend of the IDE you are using

Comment: I have osmorc installed on my IDEA instance. I'll check for maven-bundle-plugin as well.

Comment: Hi @christian.vogel, the link you have provided does not work. Could you please update it so others can make use of your answer. Thanks.